# Is the relative interior of a subspace which is not closed empty?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

In a general Banach space, the relative interior of a linear subspace which is not closed is empty, why ?

Comment: What do you mean by "relative interior"?

Comment: The _relative_ interior of a subspace, inderstood as the interior in the topology of that subspace, would be the subspace itself. Every space is open in its own topology.

Comment: By the relative interior of a set C I mean the interior of C relative to its closed affine hull.

Comment: To me it seems redundant to speak of the "closed affine hull" of a subspace.  All subspaces are closed under affine combinations.  Perhaps you have in mind a subset that is *not* a subspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U$ be a subspace of a Banach space $V$. Suppose $x\in U$ is an interior point of $U$, which means that
$$
B(x,\varepsilon)=\{y:\|x-y\|<\varepsilon\}\subseteq U
$$
for some $\varepsilon>0$. Since $U$ is a subspace, also
$$
B(0,\varepsilon)=-x+B(x,\varepsilon)
$$
is contained in $U$. Now, for every $v\in V$, $v\ne0$, the vector
$$
\frac{1}{2\varepsilon\|v\|}v\in B(0,\varepsilon)
$$
which means that $U$ contains a scalar multiple of every nonzero vector. Therefore $U=V$.

So the only subspace of $V$ that has interior points is $V$ itself (provided $V\ne\{0\}$).